# Adding a class with "Display:none" to an element is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div which i want to hide (display:none).

Html:

```
<div class="alert">
        <div class="notice">
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Notice:</h1><i class="fas fa-window-close"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <p>You must select at least one seat to Continue.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <button>Ok</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Css:

```
.alert {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgb(252, 238, 235, 0.4);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  user-select: none;
}
```

**when i add the below class it doesn't work at all, but it does work on adding properties to that same class like color,margin,padding... but it doesn't work on "display:none" and it also works when i enter css through js like 
$('element').css('display','none')**
css:

```
.noticeClose {
  display: none;
}
```

js/jquery:

```
 $("div.bookingBtn input").click(function () {
    if ($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length == 0) {
      $("div.alert").addClass("noticeClose");
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Hava a nice day!

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like there's an other style that overrides the display property.

try next

```css
.noticeClose {
  display: none!important;
}
```

if it doesn't work then maybe `hide`

```js
 $("div.bookingBtn input").click(function () {
    if ($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length == 0) {
      $("div.alert").hide();
      return false;
    }
  });
```

also this doesn't work too - try to debug to assure that `div.alert` gets the `noticeClose` class after a click.

Comment: yup! that solves everything, thanks :) (display: none!important; worked). btw i am adding class because i want to add some animations.